# Using ShareCompat and FileProvider from Android service instead of activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-sharing

I have watched Sharing Content episode from Android Developers Patterns and they use `ShareComapt.IntentReader` and `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder` to share and receive easily intents. Is there any way to use this `ShareCompat` especially handling streams (files and images)  using FileProvider but from Android service?

Comment: Well, `ACTION_SEND` is only for activities, and that is what `ShareCompat` is for. You are welcome to take information from the `ACTION_SEND` received by an activity and pass it to a service if you want.

Comment: But when we want to be transparent for the user is the best option to open some invisible activity or what is the best practice?

Comment: I do not know what "be transparent for the user" means. There is nothing stopping you from having a `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar` activity respond to the `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` and trigger some background work for the actual sending. However, users expect *some* UI reaction to a request to share content. If you do nothing, users will think that perhaps they didn't tap on the right item, or that their tap was missed, or that your app is broken. At minimum, use a `Toast`, but I would think that it is better to have something bigger (e.g., dialog-themed activity). That's just my opinion, though.

Comment: But what happened when I want to share documents and images to be processed by android service? It is a good option for pending intent which start result activity when work is done or if we stick to transparent, not visible activity.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand your question.

Comment: I want third party applications to share images and documents to my android service for processing. After processing finished I want to provide result via Intent for example to caller component.

Comment: Then I fail to see what `ShareCompat` has to do with any of this. `ACTION_SEND` does not offer "result via Intent". `ShareCompat.IntentBuilder` only configures an action bar item to trigger `startActivity()`. If you want to borrow some ideas or conventions from `ACTION_SEND` and `ShareCompat`, that's fine, but you will still have to build your own protocol using those ideas or conventions.